# Need help finishing ruby on rails reservations web app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm attempting to code a reservation web app using ruby on rails, and I'm running into a bit of trouble. I've created the following models:
    +User
    +Restaurant 
    +Tables
    +Reservation

I've setup the relationships, but I'm struggling to assign a user and table to a new reservation. Is there an analogy to current_user that I can use to match the table to a reservation? Also what about restaurants - how do I make sure the user sets tables when they make a new restaurant?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll be better doing this:

```
#app/models/reservation.rb
Class Reservation < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user
    belongs_to :table
end

#app/models/user.rb
Class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :reservations
    has_many :tables, through: :reservations
end

#app/models/restaurant.rb
Class Restaurant < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :tables
    has_many :reservations, through: :tables
end

#app/models/table.rb
Class Table < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :restaurant

    has_many :reservations
    has_many :users, through: :reservations
end
```

This means you'll be able to use the [`<<` ActiveRecord method](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html) to add your users / tables to the reservations collection, or just create the reservation directly:

```
#app/controllers/reservations_controller.rb
Class Reservation < ApplicationController
    def create
       reservation = Reservation.new(reservation_params)
       reservation.save
    end

    private

    def reservation_params
        params.require(:reservation).permit(:user_id, :table_id)
    end
end
```

Answer (score 3):

You can set up a many to many relationship using `:through`, here's the [link](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-through-association) to the docs.

You can do it something like this.

User model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :reservations
  has_many :tables, through: :reservations
end
```

Table model:

```
class Table < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :reservations
  has_many :users, through: :reservations
end
```

Reservation model:

```
class Reservation < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :table
end
```

Then you just create a new table for a user like: `user.table = some_table`